# How to translate this code from common lisp to clojure

Tags: clojure, common-lisp

In common lisp I can place multiple `defun` in the same closure and have them all set functions.

```
(let ((number 0))
  (defun get-number () number)
  (defun set-number ( arg ) (setq number arg)))
```

How ever if I use the same syntax in clojure only the last function ends up getting defined.

```
(let [ number 0 ]
  (defn get-number [] number)
  (defn set-number [ arg ] (def number arg)))
```

Is there a way to translate this code into clojure so that you have access to both functions?

Comment: You can use DEFUN inside a LET in Common Lisp, but I won't generally recommend it. DEFUN is no longer a top-level form inside the LET, which has slight drawbacks for compilation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[user593508 gives a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11597530/214010) in terms of a literal translation.

But it's a bit unidiomatic in Clojure, where the use of data encapsulated behind side-effectful setters and getter functions is discouraged. Clojure tends to emphasize pure functions, and explicit control of state though managed references (see this [excellent video by Rich Hickey on data structures and managed references](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Value-Identity-State-Rich-Hickey))

An alternative would be to use an atom directly to store the mutable number:

```
(def number (atom 0))

@number
=> 0

(swap! number + 5)
=> 5

@number
=> 5
```

Apart from being more concise and more idiomatic Clojure, you get the extra advantage that `swap!` can execute aribtrary functions on the atom's value, not just getting and setting (see the example with +5 above)

Answer (score 5):

Here is one possible translation of your code - the get-number function is accessible.

```
(let [number (atom 0)]
  (defn get-number []
    @number)
  (defn set-number [arg]
    (reset! number arg)))

(get-number) => 0
(set-number 5)
(get-number) => 5
```